# File path for excel file

Tags: python, pandas, file, filepath, xls

I have the file EnergyIndicators.xls, which I want to read into python so I can manipulate it.

How can I obtain the **file path** so I can read the file in using the:

**pd.read_excel()** function?

Comment: what do you mean? Would you like to find a file called "EnergyIndicators.xls" on your computer?

Comment: My question is how to find the file path in a pre-written form (where you can copy and paste the link): how to find the file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get excel file location from the file info and use this reference for syntax.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_excel.html
Pretty straightforward.

Comment: My question is how to find the file path in a pre-written form (where you can copy and paste the link): how to find the file path?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to know the path to the file in your file system.

Then you just simply pass the path to `xls` file to `read_excel` function.

- `pd.read_excel('path/to/direct/EnergyIndicators.xls')`

Comment: My question is how to find the file path in a pre-written form (where you can copy and paste the link): how to find the file path?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the xls file with his absolute path or relative path to the script trying to access it as such:

```
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/your/file.xls')
```

Depending on your OS you could get the path to the file in different ways:

For Linux in the terminal once inside the folder containing your file:

```
pwd #this will get the current working folder
```

In Windows you can simply navigate to the location where your file is located and click in the navigato bar to get the path to the directory.

Comment: My question is how to find the file path in a pre-written form (where you can copy and paste the link): how to find the file path?